# How to check from elisp if isearch is in progress?

Tags: isearch

I have a background process which when finishes switches to a specific buffer. I don't want this process to interrupt my current isearch if I'm doing one, so I'd like to test if an isearch is in progress, and delay switching to that buffer if it is the case.

How can I do this? I tried checking `this-command` from the process handler, but it is `nil` for some reason even if I'm in an isearch.

Comment: Maybe you can use a *mutex* to solve the problem? I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried checking `this-command` from the process handler, but it is `nil` for some reason even if I'm in an `isearch`.

This is because the isearch process is not one command, but a series of commands.  Each time you type `C-s` (for instance) during an isearch, that's an independent trip around the command loop.

The buffer-local variable `isearch-mode` is non-nil while an isearch is in process in a given buffer, and set to nil again by `isearch-done`, so simply checking that variable in the selected window's buffer is probably sufficient.

You could also use `isearch-mode-hook` and `isearch-mode-end-hook` to track the state, but I suspect that's unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, checking isearch-mode works. Thanks.